# Can an active Postgres serverlog be truncated?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, logs

Running Postgres 9.1 on Ubuntu 14.10 LTS.

I've got an application running on a machine that's going to run out of diskspace soon.  However, the application is in the middle of a crucial run that has taken 6 days thus far, and canceling it would mean another 6-day run.

I've deleted everything I can for which I have permissions, but I'd like to truncate the server log to free up some space.

If I were to copy the server log off and then do a `cp /dev/null /database/serverlog` would I risk causing the server to hang?  Or since the file reference has not changed, will it keep chugging along?

I realize the server log I copy off will have incomplete entries at the end and the new servlog will have incomplete entries at the beginning, so it's obviously not an optimal situation if I had to try to restore data using those files as there would be transactions missing.  However, I think the likelihood of actually needing to use the serverlog files before I have a chance to reconfigure and restart the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default PostgreSQL logs to `stderr`, from PostgreSQL Documentation [18.8. Error Reporting and Logging:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html)

> PostgreSQL supports several methods for logging server messages, including stderr, csvlog and syslog. On Windows, eventlog is also supported. Set this parameter to a list of desired log destinations separated by commas. **The default is to log to stderr only.** This parameter can only be set in the postgresql.conf file or on the server command line.

If you just direct `stderr` to file according to the documentation this means you have to stop and restart the server to truncate, [23.3. Log File Maintenance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/logfile-maintenance.html):

> **If you simply direct the stderr of postgres into a file, you will have log output, but the only way to truncate the log file is to stop and restart the server.** This might be acceptable if you are using PostgreSQL in a development environment, but few production servers would find this behavior acceptable.

About manually deleting the file, take a look at [this thread](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BD69807DAE0CE44CA00A8338D0FDD0830185A615A8@oma00cexmbx03.corp.westworlds.com) from PostgreSQL mailing lists (from year 2010):

> What platform?  If in Unix/Linux, just:
>   cat /dev/null > postgres_logfile
>   or
>   postgres_logfile
>   Most running programs **don't like it when you delete a file** with an open file handle but you **it doesn't mind if you clear it on the fly.**  Not sure how to do this in a Windows environment.

And finally here's [a good blog post](http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/11/dear-postgresql-where-are-my-logs.html) more generally about PostgreSQL logs.