# Is it okay for me to truncate the postgresql serverlog file?

Tags: postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL 13.0 on RedHat, 64-bit but my serverlog file has grown so big (29 GB).

I would like to know if its safe to clear contents for this file by using `> serverlog` or any other command that will clear all the contents in the file.

I looked around and could not find any documentation on whether its safe to do this. Most documentation talks of changing the logging strategy or configs but I do not have that level of access to achieve the configuration changes. Sample advice - [Can an active Postgres serverlog be truncated?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94828/can-an-active-postgres-serverlog-be-truncated)

Current space utilization for the serverlog file

`-rw-r--r--  1 postgres postgres  29G Dec 10 14:16 serverlog`

Comment: Yes, you can do that in the way you suggest. Or change `log_rotation_size` and reload.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe, this worked for me.
Can you add this as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truncating the log file with

```bash
> logfile
```

should work.

If you have `logging_collector = on` (typically, if you are *not* using the Ubuntu or Debian binaries), you can also set `log_rotation_size` to the desired maximum and reload (not restart) PostgreSQL.